# How to go to a specific line in a java script file in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Most of the time we are dealing with big java script files. And while debugging we need to locate specific line in script files. I realized that there is no information for this in stackoverflow, and wanted to supply answer here. This is how to go to a specific line in a java script file in Chrome Developer Tools. See the answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While a java script file is open in the sources tab, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> type a colon and line number after it :[LineNo] (:575 etc) enter.

If you want to go to specific column on a specific line then use two colons to specify line number and column number at the same time :[LineNo]:[ColumnNo] (:575:50 etc) enter.

Answer (score 7):

`Ctrl + G` / `Cmd + G` like anywhere else.

Your solution requires a one more step to achieve the goal

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + G for Mac so that you don't have to type `:`. Other options is to press CMD+P and type `:` and type the line number.

Answer (score 1):

The information you mentioned is documented by Umar on the Google Developers web site.

> **GOTO** a line number with a specified column using the format
>   **:linenumber:columnnumber** in the CMD+O dialogue from the Sources panel
>   editor.
>
> 1. Hit CMD + O from the Sources Panel with an open file
> 2. Enter :5:9
> 3. Notice you are taken to line 5, column 9!

[image: Go to a line number at a specific column]

**Source:** 
[Go to a line number at a specific column](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/go-to-a-line-number-at-a-specific-column)

Answer (score 0):

everyone here is correct about the CMD+G but you can actually set it up to whatever you want in the settings.

I personally set it to be the same shortkey as the intellij IDE

[image]